# Compilers, finding FIRST set for grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I am reading the famous violet dragon book 2nd edition, and can't get the example from page 65, about creating the FIRST set:

We have the following grammar (terminals are bolded):

> *stmt* → **expr;**
>               | **if** ( **expr** ) stmt
>               | **for** ( optexpr ; optexpr ; optexpr ) stmt
>               | **other**
>
> optexpr → ε
>               | **expr**

And the book suggests that the following is the correct calculation of FIRST:

> FIRST(stmt) → {**expr**, **if**, **for**, **other**} // agree on this
>
> FIRST(**expr ;**) → {**expr**} // Where does this come from?

As the comment suggests, from where does the second line come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no error in the textbook.

The `FIRST` function is defined (on page 64, emphasis added):

> Let `α` be a **string of grammar symbols** (terminals and/or nonterminals). We define `FIRST(α)` to be the set of terminals that appear as the first symbols of one or more strings of terminals **generated from α**.

In this example, **expr** **;** is a string of grammar symbols consisting of two terminals, so it is a possible value of α. Since it includes no nonterminals, it cannot only generate itself; thus the only string of terminals generated from that value of α is precisely **expr** **;**, and the only terminal that will appear in `FIRST(α)` is the first symbol in that string, **expr**.

This may all seem to be belabouring the obvious, but it leads up to the important note just under the example you cite:

> The `FIRST` sets must be considered if there are two productions `A → α` and `A → β`. Ignoring ε-productions for the moment, **predictive parsing requires `FIRST(α)` and `FIRST(β)` to be disjoint**.

Since **expr ;** is one of the possible right-hand sides for `stmt`, we need to compute its `FIRST` set (even though the computation in this case is trivial) in order to test this prerequisite.

Comment: I agree that **expr;** is possible value of α, and {**expr**} is valid set. But why we need compute `FIRST(expr;)`? To what `expr` in last sentence refers to?

Comment: @sonny: oops, typed that wrong. I meant `stmt`. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: No problem, thanks for explaining obvious things.So, second `FIRST(expr;)` is just an arbitrary example. If author goals was check if `FIRST` sets are disjoint, he should checks all productions for `stmt`. But to save paper only one was explicity show.

Comment: @sonny exactly.